# Currents and magnetic fields produce forces that affect things they're not touching?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

I was doing [this](http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/62267-question-paper-unit-g485-fields-particles-and-frontiers-of-physics.pdf) past paper and am a little confused by question 5) part c)ii)

[image: Diagram from past paper]

[image: force on current carrying wire from magnetic field]

[image: how this force affects the balance]

I correctly calculated that the force acting on the rod due to the magnetic field is 0.016N but I can't see how this could affect the scales as they're not touching.
I had a look at the [mark scheme](http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/58522-mark-scheme-unit-g485-fields-particles-and-frontiers-of-physics-june.pdf) but I can't understand why Newton's 3rd law would apply when the two objects aren't touching?

Here is a print screen of the mark scheme for part c):

[image: mark scheme]

Could anyone explain this please?

Thank you :)

Comment: Two bar magnets can attract each other without touching, right? I mean, that is how a magnetic compass works. So forces without contact are a reasonably common occurrence. Could you be more specific about what is troubling you on that score? (BTW--the Newton's 3rd law part of the question may be deeper than you think.)

Comment: Oh okay sorry. What I don't get is why just because the rod moves down, this affects the the magnet at all. I think I'm probably not full understanding the affects of the rod moving. Is it that because the rod has a current through it and is moving through a magnetic field in exerts a force? Sorry if this isn't very clear either.

Comment: Have you covered the magnetic field due to a current yet? From there it is reasonable to determine the direction of the counter force. Showing that it is actually equal and opposite is a bit harder.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, we have covered that and I think I might get it now. I've found an image of what I think is going on here (but it's other way round in our diagram) http://www.one-school.net/Malaysia/UniversityandCollege/SPM/revisioncard/physics/electromagnetism/images/catapult-field.png So both magnetic fields are being affected? However, what I don't understand now is why the magnet still feels that upward force when the current carrying wire (and its magnetic field) is outside of its own magnetic field? Thank you!